# Retrieve a data frame from a list of data frames r

Tags: r, dataframe

I had a data frame like so:

```
name letter
Sam a
Sam b
Sam a
Harry b
Harry c
Bob a
Bob b
```

which then I split into a list of data frames, one data frame for each name

```
sp = split(df1,df1$name)
```

What can I do if I want to retrieve the data frame with the name "Sam" from it quickly?

I know sp[[1]] does the trick, but I want to retrieve based on the name, and not the index resides within the list.

I also thought about doing an associative array, but don't know if that's the best way or not.

```
"Sam" -> sp[[1]]
"Harry" -> sp[[2]]
"Bob" -> sp[[3]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use either

```
sp$Sam
```

Or

```
sp[['Sam']]
```

Answer (score 0):

why do you want to split the data frame in the beginning? what you want you can just do it with data frame:

```
df_sam <- df[df$name == "Sam",]
```